# How do I set the number of threads in OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to set the number of threads within a program using OpenMP. For some reason, even though the maximum number of threads is 4, my program only uses 1 core. I'm on MacOSX but I'm using the gcc compiler (specifically: gcc9.1.0 and OpenMP version 4.5)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  int maxthreads = omp_get_max_threads();

  std::cout << "maxthreads: " << maxthreads << std::endl;

  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_num_threads(4);
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
  {
     int id = omp_get_thread_num();
     #pragma omp critical
     std::cout << "Hi from " << id << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The result that I get is:

```
4
Hi from 0
```

But I expected "Hi from i" to be printed 4 times.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But there is no loop. Shouldn't it just create 4 threads that print "Hi"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add flags to my cmake:

`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fopenmp` and `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fopenmp`